# Why does the application stops in address sanitizer build?

Tags: c++, objective-c++, address-sanitizer

I have a code similar to below code

**A.mm**

```
- (void)Foo {
    const unsigned long long dataLen = 0; // In a particular case dataLen is 0
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataLen];
    b->TestGetData(data.mutableBytes, data.length);
}
```

**B.cpp**

```
void B::TestGetData(void* data,
                    unsigned long long dataLength) {
    memset(data, 0, (size_t)dataLength);
    
    std::string reqBody = ""; // in a particular case reqBody is empty
    memcpy(data, reqBody.c_str(), dataLength);
    printf("[data = %s]", (char*)data);
}
```

When I build the application using AddressSanitizer the program stops with

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x267dd) in printf_common(void*, char const*, __va_list_tag*)

{
  "access_size" : 2,
  "access_type" : 0,
  "address" : 105690556485681,
  "description" : "heap-buffer-overflow",
  "instrumentation_class" : "AddressSanitizer",
  "pc" : 4539582430,
  "stop_type" : "fatal_error"
}
```

but there is no issue when the application is build without AddressSanitizer

Also in case of AddressSanitizer I noticed that the bytes at memory address of `data` were `BE 00 00 00 ...` but without AddressSanitizer the bytes were `00 00 00 ...`

I am not able to understand:

1. where does byte `\XBE` come from?
2. why there is an issue in AddressSanitizer build?
3. why does it report *heap-buffer-overflow*?

Comment: You have Undefined Behaviour - AddressSanitizer found it for you. The code zeros `data` for `dataLength` bytes and then copies `reqBody.c_str()` for `dataLength` into `data` if the next byte of `data` (which is still initialised) is not zero then `printf` will try to print a non `0` terminated string.

Comment: typo in the above _"...(which is still initialised)..."_ -> _"...(which is still __uninitialised)__..."_

Comment: Also in the code `memcpy(data, reqBody.c_str(), dataLength);` unless `dataLength < 2 ` you have Undefined Behaviour as `reqBody` was set to the empty string on the line above.

Comment: In the above code dataLength = 0; and as already mentioned the bytes address pointed by data are BE 00 00 (i.e. 0 terminated)